# tail -F & grepをlessへ移行できるか

Tags: linux

ログ監視コマンドに「tail -F」を使用しており、これを「less」へ移行できないか考えております。

現在は、ログファイルがローテートしても完全にエラーを監視したいため、このようにsh化しております。

```sh
tail -F log.log |grep 'Error\|ERROR\|エラー\|異常'
```

また、エラーが多発した際はtmuxの検索機能を利用しているので、検索も使いたいです。

これらの機能をlessへ落とし込み、最終的にsh化を目指すと以下の実現可能な問題と、そうではない問題が挙げられると思います。

**実現可能**

1. 「tail -F 」でlogファイルを流すことができる
2. 検索機能はlessにあるのでtmuxに依存する必要はない
3. 「tail -F 」は「less --follow-name」でローテートに対応できる
4. 「|grep 'Error\|ERROR\|エラー\|異常'」のような機能は「&」を入力したらできそう？？

**問題点**

1. 「|grep 'Error\|ERROR\|エラー\|異常'」ができたとしても、lessを起動してから叩かなければならない？
2. 最終的にsh化することができない？

「tail -F|grep」の運用でも良いのですが、最近は「less」の方が良いと聞いたので、実現可能かどうか教えていただいたいです。

Comment: `less --follow-name +F '+/Error|ERROR|エラー|異常' log.log` とすればご期待に添えるかもしれません。ただ、実行時の時点で `log.log` ファイルに検索文字列が含まれていないと `Pattern not found (press RETURN)` と表示されます。

Comment: 試してみましたが、「Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)」ではなく、「log.log」として表示されております。また、検索結果をマークしてくれてますが、関係のない行も出ているようです。

Comment: こちらで使っている less は `less 487 (GNU regular expressions) Copyright (C) 1984-2016  Mark Nudelman` です。

Comment: 目的がイマイチはっきりしない気がします。`less`を使いたいのは単に**流行っていそう**だから？今までと同じ使い方が出来るなら(tail + grepを使わなければ)、例えばコマンドとしてタイプする量は増えても構わないのか等。最終的に`sh`に落とし込むのであれば、現状で困りごとが無ければ無理して`less`に切り替える必要がないですよね。

Comment: lessが古いバージョンでしたので最新化すると、ご指摘の通り「Pattern not found (press RETURN)」となり解決しました。しかし、grep結果に該当しない行も表示されており、「|grep 'Error\|ERROR\|エラー\|異常'」のような動きにはなりませんでした。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、「単純に流行っているから」が理由です。しかし、将来的に環境を再構築するとなると、検索用の「tmux」と「tail」、「grep」を導入しなければならないため、「less」のみで解決するのであれば移行したいと考えております。

Comment: なるほど、勘違いをしていました。それでは、`LESSOPEN='|grep -E "Error|ERROR|エラー|異常" "%s"' less --follow-name +F log.log` ではどうでしょうか。

Comment: ああ、でもgrepを使っているので「lessだけ」という条件に合いませんね:-p

Comment: そうですね。しかし、tmuxは省けた分は大きな一歩になります。なお、頂いたコマンドでも関係のない行がまだ表示されております。。。実現が難しそうな印象ですので、おとなしくこれまで通りの環境で監視した方が良いように思えてきました。。。。

Comment: すみません。実行していた「less」の入力に誤りがありました。「LESSOPEN='|grep -E "Error|ERROR|エラー|異常" "%s"' less --follow-name +F log.log」にて期待通りに動くことは確認できました！

Comment: ありがとうございます！期待通りに動作することを確認できました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grep に `--line-buffred` オプションをつけてフィルタした結果を `less` で表示してはどうでしょう。

`tail -F log.log | egrep --line-buffered -e 'Error|ERROR|エラー|異常' | less`

Comment: まだ試していませんが、見る限りこちらの書き方で実現できるかと思います。しかし、lessが流行している理由は「tail&grep」ではなく、lessのみで解決できる点だと思いますので、「tail」と「grep」を使用しない方法があれば知りたいです。

Comment: lessは単なるページャーですが高機能なので、ログ監視に使いたいという動機は非常に同感するものがありますが、とはいえ、Unix文化圏には「KISSの原則」というのがありまして、それに従うと正規表現によるフィルタリングは grep でやるべきだと個人的には感じる次第ではありますが、本筋とは関係ないので置いておくとして・・・。懸念されているように「&」は起動後に入力する必要があるでしょうから 実現は難しいように感じますね。

Comment: 難しいと書きましたが、対話的操作を自動化する手段として expect があります。ただ、本来の目的から離れていく感じがしますのでオススメはしません・・・。

Comment: 細かい部分を説明しますと、expectにてssh経由で外部サーバー上のtail&grepを実行させております。やはり、行き着く先は対話的動作にて自動化に行き当たってしまします。

Comment: タイトル通りである「tail&grep」をless単体で実装することは難しいと理解しました。本質問はこれにて解決済みとさせてください。また、「metropolis さん」の説明の通り「less&grep」では実装可能ということで終了とさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

コマンドの追加インストールは必要ですが、代替案を紹介しておきます。

---

**multitail**というコマンドがあり、本来の使い方としては「複数のファイルに対して同時に`tail`出来る」のがウリですが、もちろん単一のファイルに対しても実行可能です。

https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/

その他の特徴として、正規表現を使ったフィルタリングやハイライトも可能です。

```
$ multitail --retry -e "error|Error" -f tail.log
```

オプションについては`--retry`が`tail -F`相当、`-e "パターン"`で正規表現にマッチした行のみ表示されます。

コマンドのインストールはソースコードから行うか、メジャーなディストリビューションであればパッケージが用意されている場合もあるようです(CentOSならepel経由)。

---

なお、コメント欄で環境再構築時の懸念をされていますが、`tail`や`grep`をシステムに入れないのは個人的にあり得ないと思います。

Comment: tailとgrepがシステムに入っていない前提でお話したこと少し大袈裟でした。multitail を試してみましたが、結果としては一番理想に近い用に思われます。しかし、開発環境相当のためインストールを禁止しているチームであれば「multitail」が使用できない点が残念です。

Comment: ソースからのインストールであればユーザー毎のHOME以下に入れる選択肢もありますがこれも難しいのでしょうか。「OS標準のコマンドで賄いたい」という制限があるのなら、質問文に含めておくとそれに見合った回答が付くと思います（できればOSの種類などももう少し詳しく書いてあった方がよいかもしれません）。

Comment: 確かにカレントディレクトリの「bin」へ導入することで解決できますが、これすら許されない環境です。開発環境をVMペースで完全に同期を取る必要があります。しかし、SMB経由で公開されているlogファイルを「multitail」が入っている端末で監視することができるため、これも一つの解決策とさせていただきます。